# trying to use USB connection, easytether-usb and Ubuntu 18.04.2, error = interface is used by another process (hotplug?)

Tags: 18.04, usb, tethering, easytether

## The Set Up

- Phone - Moto z3 - developer mode ON, debugging mode ON
- easytether - v 1.1.19
- Ubuntu - 18.04.2

## Actions taken

1. installed easytether Pro
2. installed drivers (easytether_0.8.9_amd64.deb) 
   `dpkg -i easytether_0.8.9_amd64.deb`
3. ran following cmd
   `sudo easytether-usb`
   returns error message

```
interface tun-easytether is used by another process (hotplug?)
```

## What I've Tried

1. Restarting both phone and laptop.
2. Turned wi-fi on and off
3. Restarted the network manager `sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service`
4. Restarted the ModemManager `sudo systemctl restart ModemManager-manager.service`
5. Even though it states it's for 16.04 I added `source-directory interfaces.d` to my `etc/network/interfaces` file.
6. As per easytether pro documentation tried running the following commands

```
# systemctl enable systemd-networkd
# systemctl start systemd-networkd
```

systemd-networkd not found?

## The questions

1. Is it an issue that the interface tun-easytether is being used? If it is how can I find out whats engaging it?
2. If the process lock isn't my issue, where should I logically looking?

Comment: You could read `man fuser;man lsof` and do `sudo fuser /dev/net/tun-easyther` or `sudo lsof  /dev/net/tun-easyther` (or wherever in the `/dev` tree `tun-easytheher` is) to see what process has it open,.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Went over the easytether-pro documentation again and under Ubuntu 18.04 it instructs user to enable/start `systemd-networkd`

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd.service
```

This time I used the command-line completion on the string "systemd" and one of the results were `systemd-networkd.service`

Having the '.service' at the end seems new to 18.06.

Anywho I'm on the lines which is what matters. Hope this helps others.